# Eset antivirus cannot clean the MBR infected virus W32.Sality

Tags: boot, usb, anti-virus, mbr, eset

I'm using Eset Nod 32 antivirus, Windows 8.1 64 bit, today I meet w32.Sality virus from an USB drive, it look like the virus affected the MBR (Master boot record), all the antivirus I have detected it, but they are can't clean it at all I I must repair the drive MBR by hand. So:

1. Are there a good Antivirus program can prevent/clean the MBR virus for Windows?
2. Are there any GUI tool for repair MBR for USB in Windows running?

Comment: ask the ESET support for help

Comment: I don't think they can, it's a common problem of normal antivirus like Avast, eset, even KIS...

Comment: if you don't as them you'll never get help. I'll no longer help you.

Comment: Contact ESET;  Report the problem;  You have nothing to lose except for a few minutes of time reporting the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this question is still actual:
Changes in MBR is very dangerous operation, that's why cleaning some malware is much more difficult than removing some trojan. If AV try to fix your MBR and fail (it just can happen), you will be very angry to AV company, when your MBR will remain corrupted and you will not be able to boot your system.

But they are offers external cleaners, you can find it on their site. In your case, try to follow [these](http://kb.eset.com/esetkb/index?page=content&id=SOLN3146) steps.

ECLS.exe is located in your installation of ESET in Program Files. If you still have troubles, do not hesitate to contact their support.